# Fixed to top navbar not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, css-position

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to and I would like the menu to stick at top of the browser while scrolling. The navbar gets to the top of the browser at first but when scrolling it is scrolled away.
I am using the standard setup of a menu found at twitter bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand animated fadeInDown" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
                <img class="center brand-logo" style="margin-top: 18px;" height="30px" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/Triday-fat.png" alt="Loggan för Triday, designade hemsidor till ett lågt pris"/>
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'              => 'primary',
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                    'depth'             => 2,
                    'container'         => 'div',
                    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
            ?>
          </ul>
    </div> <!--  /. container-fluid-->
</nav>
```

and the css is the standard bootstrap but when it didn't work I have tried to add

```
.navbar { position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 60px; top: 0; }
```

I would be thankful if someone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those who have had the same problem as I, I found a solution! The problem was that I used an animate.css effect on the  tag which somehow disabled the fixed position on it's children... When the effect was removed fixed position worked! 
Thanks to you guys who helped me!

Answer (score 3):

This is all you need to have a fixed to top nav bar:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " id="top" role="banner">


</header>
```

Try it out [here](http://www.bootply.com/kPhMdlOnLG) a bootply. [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) is the docs on it.

Comment: @HannesH added a bootply for you

Comment: Do you use <header class="navbar ... instead of <nav class="navbar....? I think I have tried it both ways but it is not working for me. I have viewed the navbar in safari, chrome and FF but it is not working in either one of them, so I have ruled out any browser error.... @JordanD

Comment: @HannesH Yes header class replaces nav class, I have tested it in chrome and it works.

Comment: I have seen your bootply and I see it works but as fast as I am trying to implement it in my code it doesn't work...... @JordanD

Comment: @HannesH there is a chance maybe your php is interfering, i would take out a line of code at a time to see at what point the header works.

Comment: I have inspected the elements and I have looked at this example setup [link](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) and I have compared to my code. And I have the exact same css markup as in the example page! But still it is not kept at the top of the browser @JordanD

Comment: Can it be the php that is the problem? Because now I took all my code and replaced it with the bootstrap.css file and it still didn't work. Do you have to include any bootstrap css map or bootstrap.js for fixed-top navbar? @JordanD

Comment: @HannesH all the bootstrap features should work if you include bootstrap.js

Comment: Could you please take a look at my site, I am working on an update with fixed navbar but all the bootstrap files and the php are the same except that I have not added the class, "navbar-fixed-top" to the <nav> yet. When I try to strip my php down it still doesn't work and I really don't know what do do :( [link](http://www.triday.se)

Answer (score 0):

add top:0px;

This probably wil fix.

Comment: sorry I forgot to write that, but that was with my testing css and it didn't work either :( @user1496

Comment: 0 & 0px have the same effect. 0 is the only value that doesn't need a value definition

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a z-index: 1000; which was applied on a div#header where my nav.navbar-fixed-top was in.

When I removed the z-index, my menu was moving smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

If u are using **animate.css** then add

```
position: fixed !important;
```

to

```
navbar-fixed-top
```

It works..

Comment: please use code block instead of bold for your answers